# Notification icon for wireless connection when using /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: wireless, network-manager, icons, startup, notification

I have modified `/etc/network/interfaces` in order to connect to my wireless network automatically on startup.

*My question:* Is there a way, to put a notification icon on the top panel to confirm that the computer is connected.

Now the only icon is the one of `nm` which is being bypassed so is not useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `nm` to include any interfaces that you defined in `/etc/network/interfaces` by editing its configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and changing `managed=false` to `managed=true` in the `[ifupdown]` section

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Comment: if I do that, then it won't connect on startup.